# Failure exit codes not returning on CentOS 7.7.1908 for `yum update`

Tags: bash, centos, yum

I am trying to work around a `[Errno -1] Metadata file does not match checksum` error on `yum update` by implementing a retry loop, but for some reason `yum` is returning with a `0` each time.

Here is a sequence:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# Create a copy of the yum.conf file and set "http_caching=none"
cp /etc/yum.conf /tmp/yum.conf
sed -i 's/http_caching=packages/http_caching=none/g' /tmp/yum.conf
# Add an additional "http_caching=none" line in case the file does not already contain an "http_caching" property
echo -e "\nhttp_caching=none" >> /tmp/yum.conf

# Clear local caches
yum clean all --config=/tmp/yum.conf --disableplugin=fastestmirror
yum clean metadata --config=/tmp/yum.conf --disableplugin=fastestmirror
rm -fr /var/cache/yum

# Run update
yum update -y --config=/tmp/yum.conf --disableplugin=fastestmirror 2>&1
result=$?

echo $result
```

Despite seeing this in the results:

```
Loaded plugins: langpacks
http://olcentgbl.trafficmanager.net/centos/7/os/x86_64/repodata/primary.sqlite.bz2: [Errno -1] Metadata file does not match checksum
Trying other mirror.
No packages marked for update
```

The `$result` variable contains a value of `0` and the retry loop is not iterating.  If `2>&1` is not included, the message is sent to `stderr`, so there should be failure exit code returned.

Any ideas why `yum` isn't returning the expected result?

Any insight is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe it believes that it successfully updated all 0 packages it was aware of?

Comment: If that's the case, do you see any ways to implement a retry loop?  Eventually the `yum update` command works after waiting a few minutes.  Capturing and parsing the output seems inefficient.

Comment: I would just set LC_ALL, slap a `grep -q` on it, and explain in a comment.